# RTP packages calculate losses

Tags: algorithm, audio, voip, rtp

I found that you can do that by making some calculations on the sequence numbers from the RTP header. But the sequence numbers are stored in 16bits and could easily exceed the limit of these 16bits.
  So how do you deal with this? How do you calculate the packages lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered very nicely in the [Colin Perkins book: RTP: audio and video for the internet, pages 75 and 76](http://books.google.co.za/books?id=OM7YJAy9_m8C&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=RTP%20extended%20sequence%20number%20modulo%20arithmetic&source=bl&ots=hVFFYIoWE8&sig=5v34P8dNVM__V2UIrId8aMgwWw0&hl=en&ei=aEQDTsKsDMWJhQea8eiVDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=RTP%20extended%20sequence%20number%20modulo%20arithmetic&f=false). If you google the title, it shows up (currently) in google books. He explains it excellently so do take a read online. Well worth buying this book, if you're doing any serious RTP work.

Comment: Thanks this has been really useful I implemented it and it seems to work well.